# Как получить статистику из Google AdSense по определенному URL из сайта?

Tags: google-adsense

Как можно получить статистику, например количество кликов и сумма дохода за отдельную страницу с сайта?
Реально ли вообще такое?

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307270/

Comment: добавил вопрос на форуме AdSense: https://support.google.com/adsense/thread/107940277

Comment: А здесь нет ничего?: https://developers.google.com/adsense

Comment: Посмотрел, есть возможность добавления фильтров в отчеты, но фильтр для URL нету